# How do I get "maxValuesPerFacet" in Algolia Search to work with a multiple index query?

Tags: search, algolia

I am trying to execute the query below on my indices, but the responses I get seem to not respect the maxValuesPerFacetParam. I would ideally expect 1 record from each of the facets to be retrieved using the below query. Is that now how it is expected to behave?

```
curl -X POST \                                             ✱
 -H "X-Algolia-API-Key: ${API_KEY}" \
 -H "X-Algolia-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
 --data-binary "{ \"requests\": [
                  { \"indexName\": \"index1\", \"params\": \"query=*&maxValuesPerFacet=1&hitsPerPage=5&facetFilters=(cat:life,cat:politics,cat:sports,cat:ideas,cat:design)\" },
                  { \"indexName\": \"index2\", \"params\": \"query=*\" }
                ]}" \
"https://${APPLICATION_ID}-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?strategy=none"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `maxValuesPerFacet` is not the number of hits retrieved per facet value; but rather the number of facet values per facet. Ex: you've a `category` attribute that you facet on, if you put `maxValuesPerFacet=2` it means the retrieved facets will have 2 values max (like `Electronics` and `Food`).

If you want to limit the number of results sharing a specific attribute value, you should take a look at the [distinct](https://www.algolia.com/doc/search/distinct#distinct-for-grouping) feature, it seems to fit exactly what you're describing.